# Android ANR - how do I investigate and resolve an ANR?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, admob

**Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. Wait queue length: 25. Wait queue head age: 8537.5ms.)**

Our app is getting ANRs, recently it increased on android 8.1, 7.1 devices, backtraces are attached, it is related to chrome.apk, i am using ADMob ads.
And as cloud server we are using amazon s3.

as we can see

0000000000e9b133  /system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk (???)

ANR in 0000000000018cf0 /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x758ec9d0 self=0x7fa6643a00
  | sysTid=12096 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7faa60aaa0
  | state=S schedstat=( 6194778734 462347766 3791 ) utm=525 stm=94 core=7 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fc0b3d000-0x7fc0b3f000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000001bf2c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 000000000006793c  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_cond_wait+96)
  #02  pc 000000000003c54c  /system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk (???)
  at org.chromium.ui.base.WindowAndroid.nativeOnVSync (Native method)
  at org.chromium.ui.base.WindowAndroid.access$700 (WindowAndroid.java:134)
  at org.chromium.ui.base.WindowAndroid$1.onVSync$5166USJ75THMGSJFDLKNAR9FELKIULIJF5N66JBFDPKN8RRI7D52ILG_0 (WindowAndroid.java:16)
  at org.chromium.ui.VSyncMonitor$1.doFrame (VSyncMonitor.java:22)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:874)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:688)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:620)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:862)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:754)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:163)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6238)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:933)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: Are you facing app not responding problem,
in ANR case start another tread for that to make your app responsive
you can read more 
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr

Comment: @MohsinShoukat i know that, already read documenatton many months ago. That is not the issue. Issue in Admob ADS Sdk. ANR occures in chromium app, not exactly in our app. Issue is reported on google forums from alot of developers already.